# Outlook 2010 resizes Header Image. FIX?

Tags: html, image, resize, outlook

I am programming a HTML email newsletter template. I have tested it in every browser and email host possible and it all looks great. When it gets to outlook 2010 it looks great in preview mode. But when you double click and go to full mode it takes the header image and enlarges it bigger than the table width.

I have read some and they recommend re-saving the images as 96dpi images instead of 72dpi. STILL NO HELP!!!! I have read through my code multiple times but I still can't find a fix.

Any help would be great!

My code is bellow. Can somebody proof read it and let me know if I have done anything wrong and if there is a fix

Cheers

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templatePreheader">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;height:15px;">

              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" id="templateImage">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:599px;">
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/S1MPLE/system/layouts/David%27s%20Designs/chefCode/top2.jpg" style="max-width: 599px; height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0;" alt="Image">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"  align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#ff0000;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
              This message is from Simple and Cheney Brothers.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"  align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#1b4456;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              Dear {{ offer.employee.first_name }}, 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
             {{ deal.details|capfirst|linebreaksbr }}  
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:20px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              Sign Up & Save
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              Go to: <a href="http://www.simplebrs.com/" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;"> www.simplebrs.com</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>

     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599">
          <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              username: <span style="color:#000000;">{{ offer.employee.email }}</span>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:10px;"">
              call toll free: <span style="color:#000000;">1-877-302-0560</span>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:25px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              password: <span style="color:#000000;">getdeals</span>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:25px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;"">
              call toll free: <span style="color:#000000;"> <a href="mailto:help@simpledealsnow.com" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;">help@simpledealsnow.com</a></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>

     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" id="templateImage">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:599px;">
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/S1MPLE/system/layouts/David%27s%20Designs/chefCode/bottom2.jpg" style=width: 599px; height: 77px; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0;width:599px;" alt="Image">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>

     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templatePreheader">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;height:15px;">

              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I looked at your code more detailed. You have a bunch of validation issues with the HTML.

Instead of saying what was was wrong I have cleaned up the code and reposted it below. I am hoping that this will work out for you.

There were quotations off, an extra  at the end. I also changed some of your ID="" attributes (just added numbers to the end of them). ID attributes should be distinct (standard protocol).

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templatePreheader1">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;height:15px;">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer1" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" id="templateImage2">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:599px;">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/S1MPLE/system/layouts/David%27s%20Designs/chefCode/top2.jpg" style="max-width: 599px; height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0;" alt="Image">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer2" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"  align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#ff0000;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
          This message is from Simple and Cheney Brothers.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"  align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#1b4456;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
          Dear {{ offer.employee.first_name }}, 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
         {{ deal.details|capfirst|linebreaksbr }}  
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:20px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
          Sign Up & Save
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
          Go to: <a href="http://www.simplebrs.com/" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;"> www.simplebrs.com</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer3" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599">
          <tr>
              <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
              username: <span style="color:#000000;">{{ offer.employee.email }}</span>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:10px;">
              call toll free: <span style="color:#000000;">1-877-302-0560</span>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td valign="top" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:25px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
              password: <span style="color:#000000;">getdeals</span>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom:25px;padding-top:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;">
              call toll free: <span style="color:#000000;"> <a href="mailto:help@simpledealsnow.com" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#1b4456;line-height:18px;">help@simpledealsnow.com</a></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templateContainer4" style="border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599" id="templateImage1">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;width:599px;">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/S1MPLE/system/layouts/David%27s%20Designs/chefCode/bottom2.jpg" style="width: 599px; height: 77px; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0;width:599px;" alt="Image">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="599px" id="templatePreheader2">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;height:15px;">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And it's still expanding it beyond it's own width?

Comment: @David I changed the answer. I hope this might fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I sent an html email, via exact target, to several users in our office with just 1 user having the problem you described above.

What actual caused the issue was the DPI setting on that 1 machine was set to 125%. I had them change it back to 100% (default) which solved the issue. So, essentially, nothing to do with code or image size/dpi

Here's a link on changing dpi setting in Windows 7.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/change-your-monitors-dots-per-inch-dpi-setting.html